# Add column to Alfresco Pooled Tasks table

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to change the column layout (add/remove/reorder) of
the Pooled Tasks table in Alfresco?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should modify the YUI datatable. Ie, take a look at the file share/components/task-list.js.

There is a columnDefs variable, which shows the columns:

```
 columnDefinitions:
               [
                  { key: "id", sortable: false, formatter: this.bind(this.renderCellIcons), width: 40 },
                  { key: "title", sortable: false, formatter: this.bind(this.renderCellTaskInfo) },
                  { key: "name", sortable: false, formatter: this.bind(this.renderCellActions), width: 200 }
               ],
```

Now, you can add or remove columns there.

Of course, YUI takes the data from the datasource at this URL:

```
var url = Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "api/task-instances?authority=" + encodeURIComponent(Alfresco.constants.USERNAME) +
               "&properties=" + ["bpm_priority", "bpm_status", "bpm_dueDate", "bpm_description"].join(",") +
               "&exclude=" + this.options.hiddenTaskTypes.join(",");
```

That means that you also need to modify that webscript or find the extra data you need. For more, take a look at the JSON that you get from file **"alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/workflow/workflow.lib.ftl"**

Comment: I don't see task-list.js or workflow.lib.ftl anywhere. I'm using Alfresco 2.1.

Comment: Actually it's Alfresco 3.11, sorry

Comment: Well I do remember having some of the stuff on 3.0. But, I think that the pooled tasks are a custom thing? Anyway, do you have anything in share/components/workflow? Some frontend JS?

Comment: I'm not using Share. I have been searching through all of the front end code but can't find this defined anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, never did much of Explorer customization beyond displaying type-specific properties. Did you try code-wide grep of some relevant keywords, or some such technique?

Comment: Yeah, search for a lot of things. Unfortunately most of the relevant words (eg. headers) were pretty generic word like 'description' and 'status'.  Thanks

Comment: Did you get to locate the pooled tasks dashlet?